# Retrieve last string in KQL query output in Azure

Tags: azure, kql, azure-resource-graph

I am running an KQL Query in Azure Resource Graph Explorer:

```
  resources
  | where type == 'microsoft.network/virtualwans' and tags.CompanyTag =~ 'Company'
  | extend WANname = tostring(name)
  | extend VPNsite = tostring(properties.vpnSites)
```

And the output of this is

```
{"id":"/subscriptions/companysubscriptionid/resourceGroups/companyresourcegroupname/providers/Microsoft.Network/vpnSites/NAMEOFTHEWAN"}]
```

I only want the output to be the 'NAMEOFTHEWAN' out of the string.

My question is how to display the last string information of a KQL-query output?

My thought is to split each / into an Array and then run a follow-up query to show the last array value.

Comment: Try this ```resources
| where type == 'microsoft.network/virtualwans' and tags.CompanyTag =~ 'Company'
| extend WANname = tostring(name)
| extend VPNsite = tostring(properties.vpnSites)
| extend idParts = split(id, '/')
| extend WAN = array_element_at(idParts, array_length(idParts) - 1)
| project WAN```

Comment: I get this error message:

Details:
Query is invalid. Please refer to the documentation for the Azure Resource Graph service and fix the error before retrying. (Code:InvalidQuery)
Unknown function: 'array_element_at'. (Code:UnknownFunction)
Failed to analyze expression for extended column ["WAN"] (Code:InvalidExtendedExpression)

Comment: When i run your query https://i.imgur.com/2hTOMSR.png I get this output there you can easily select Name right? https://i.imgur.com/C5PAJWc.png

Comment: You are right, the WANname / name variable actually consists of the resource group name unfortunately (something that the company decided to use for). It is all about the VPNsite variable instead. https://imgur.com/a/BQNm6Pr

Here a POV

https://imgur.com/a/Cv66YB1

Comment: Based on the second link I provide, you can see the long-string where the company name is mentioned at the end. I only want that part instead of the whole output and since your answer gave an error I cannot see it as an answer.

Comment: I am saying to use this query ```resources
  | where type == 'microsoft.network/virtualwans' 
  | extend WANname = tostring(name)
  | extend VPNsite = tostring(properties.vpnSites)
  | project name ``` https://i.imgur.com/J4wahwV.png

Comment: The name is of the project is same as the resource group name https://imgur.com/a/wb993tX  - Hence, I am asking to retrieve somehow the last string of the KQL-query output since it mentions the name of the VPN site name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Retrieve last string in KQL query output in Azure
> And the output of this is `{"id":"/subscriptions/companysubscriptionid/resourceGroups/companyresourcegroupname/providers/Microsoft.Network/vpnSites/NAMEOFTHEWAN"}]`
> I only want the output to be the 'NAMEOFTHEWAN' out of the string.

My output of id is :

[image]

As your ask was to get the end of output string:

I have reproduced in my environment and Got Expected Results as below:

```
resources
  | where type == 'microsoft.network/virtualwans' 
  | extend WANname = tostring(name)
  | extend VPNsite = tostring(properties.vpnSites)
  | project id
  | extend idemo = split(id, '/') 
  | extend WAN = array_split(idemo, array_length(idemo) - 1)
  | project WAN[1]
```

Output:

[image]

I got the last String of Output and try to follow my code and you will get the result as I have got.

Comment: Glad that it Solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the reproduction code from @RithwikBojja I modified the code as follows:

```
  resources
  | where type == 'microsoft.network/virtualwans' and tags.CompanyTag =~ 'CompanyName'
  | extend WANname = tostring(name)
  | extend VPNsite = tostring(properties.vpnSites)
  | extend idemo = split(VPNsite, '/') 
  | extend WAN = array_split(idemo, array_length(idemo) - 1)
  | project WAN[1]
```

Where I mentioned the VPNsite instead of the project ID in line 4 (as mentioned before, the project ID mentions the ResourceGroupName in my situation)